# How to list service account users in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is there a way to list service account users using Keycloak API (19.x)?

I can list users using `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users`, and I can access a service user account user using GET `/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{service-account-user-id}`, if I have such an id from, say, a user login event, but is there a way to list those?

All I need are their ids and username values.

I looked through the available Keycloak REST API documentation and I could not see it under `/admin/realms/{realm}/users` or `/admin/realms/{realm}/clients`. There are also no corresponding create and update events when those users are created by flipping Service Accounts Enabled on a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no endpoint to list all the service-account users.

You'll have to iterate over all the clients and find those that are configured with service-account.

Here is a working example in Java, using the Keycloak Admin client:

```java
public void listAll() {
    final RealmResource realmResource = ...;
    final List<ClientRepresentation> clients = realmResource.clients().findAll();

    for (final ClientRepresentation client : clients) {
        if (!client.isServiceAccountsEnabled()) {
            continue;
        }
        final UserRepresentation serviceAccountUser = realmResource.clients().get(client.getId()).getServiceAccountUser();
        final String userId = serviceAccountUser.getId();
        final String userName = serviceAccountUser.getUsername());
        ...
    }
}
```

Kindly, from [Cloud-IAM](https://www.cloud-iam.com)

Comment: Duh, it was right there in the docs `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{id}/service-account-user`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This API can get user's logged events

```
GET {{baseUrl}}/admin/realms/{realm}/events?first={start_index}&max={limit_number}
```

With Master Token

Example

```
http://localhost:8180/admin/realms/my-realm/events?first=0&max=20
```

##### Requirement for setting get user logging events

I tested `Keycloak 19.0.3`

[image]

##### Result

[image]

##### UI

[image]

##### Detail item

[image]

More detail information for `events` in [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/events/login.html)

##### How to get master token

`Tests` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("master-token", jsonData.access_token);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see how my question could have been misunderstood, I mentioned events as a possible source for service account user ids. But this is great info, we are dealing with events as well.